# Ruby : find/scan/search a string in a sentence in

Tags: ruby, regex, string, search

I am trying to find a string in a sentence

`/a.**117228558440230**.24692.116944575135295/65456`

want the string after `a` and before first `.` in ruby on rails

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a simple regexp:

```
 string = '/a.117228558440230.24692.116944575135295/65456'

 regexp = /\D\.(\d*)\./
 regexp.match(string)[1]
 #=> "117228558440230"
```

Comment: does this answer satisfy the question {string after "a" and before first "."}? @spickermann

Comment: @CbaBhusal The string after the 'a' but before the first '.' is just the empty string between that two characters. But I think it is obvious what sub string he really wanted. So, yes I think it satisfies the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find the "a." then capture everything until the next "." like this:

```
result = sentence =~ /a\.(.*?)\./ && $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try to this

```
str = "/a.**117228558440230**.24692.116944575135295/65456"

str[/\D\.(\d*)\./]
=>  "*.24692."
```

This methods gives you the string if available in the sentence otherwise `nil`